# How can you remember a user's settings while multple browser instances are open in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

I am working on an MVC3 application that has book and chapter objects. I use Session to remember settings chosen by each user. An example of a setting is last chapter viewed. It works great when users only have one browser open at a time.

Here is my challenge: Some users open up multiple browser instances at the same time. They use the same credentials to login to each instance. In one browser the last chapter viewed should be different than it is in the other browsers. Currently the session settings for a user overwrite the session settings in the other browser instances. What alternative approach can I use that will allow users to open multiple browsers and still remember the appropriate settings for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them in a hidden field on the page. Check out MVCContrib Html.Serialize to write a settings object to the page and rehydrate it on post. You can then just reference each pages object. A cookie doesn't always guarantee a unique instance especially if your browser is sharing sessions.

Comment: Thanks Adam, using a hidden field on the page will work. For anyone else facing this problem, the MVCContrib Html.Serialize part is optional. It is not a vital part of the solution.

Comment: if its basic, a hidden field works. if its a more complex object, then the Html.Serialize is nice, also you can form it in a way that the model binder will create a second object for you too from the hidden fields but this requires a prefix. I find the Html.Serialize to be a bit easier in this case:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079553/mvc-model-binding-with-multiple-entities-on-the-same-page